# ¿Es válido "salida de emergencias"?

Tags: gramática, plurales, locuciones

Leo en [un artículo](https://elpais.com/ccaa/2018/03/13/madrid/1520961608_098515.html) de El País:

> Omar se ha acostumbrado a vivir escondido. Su vida se consume en penumbra, como la vela que enciende cada noche en la estancia en la que vive: una **salida de emergencias** del entramado de túneles para el tráfico rodado que atraviesa en varios niveles el subsuelo del complejo de viviendas, bares, oficinas y grandes superficies de Azca, el conocido como distrito financiero de Madrid.

El DLE dice:

> [**de emergencia**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EiX5X40#Cn24MWE)
>
> 1. loc. adj. Que se lleva a cabo o sirve para salir de una situación de apuro o peligro.

Y de ahí, "salida de emergencia". Pero esto de "salida de emergencia**s**" es la primera vez que lo veo. ¿Es correcto?

Comment: Yo entiendo que sí, porque tal salida valdrá tanto para el concepto de "emergencia" como para todas las emergencias particulares que ocurran.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si buscas en Google los términos exactos de búsqueda, obtenemos:

- "Salida de emergencia": 12,3 millones de resultados.
- "Salida de emergencias": 1,69 millones de resultados.

Como ves, se da mucho más la versión "de emergencia", pero eso no quita para que su versión en plural sea difícil de ver, dado que hay más de millón y medio de casos en Google.

No sé si en este caso la RAE se ha limitado a recoger la versión más usada, o si es la más usada porque la RAE la recoge. En otros casos ha prevalecido la versión en plural: "[plan de estudios](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TIvEXgq#38EWqGp)" frente a "plan de estudio". También tienes "plan de inversiones" y no "de inversión".

Sí que es cierto que el concepto de *emergencia* (y no las emergencias particulares) es lo que se ha tenido en cuenta en expresiones como "salida de emergencia", "aterrizaje de emergencia" o "situación de emergencia". Se puede entender como "salida [en caso] de emergencia", pero también podrías decir "de emergencias", como en "salida para [cuando hay] emergencias". A fin de cuentas, la acepción 25 de "de" es "para".

Vamos, que no lo veo mal. El caso de "salida de emergencia" es un sustantivo con una locución adjetival, y "salida de emergencias" son dos sustantivos unidos con una preposición.

Comment: No hay que olvidar que en los Hospitales existen "Servicios de emergencias" y que los accesos reservados a los vehículos de este servicio aparecen rotulados como "emergencias".

Answer (score 2):

"Salida de emergencias" me suena como si existiera una puerta para que por ahí salgan *las emergencias* (no la gente) similar a los anuncios de "Salida de ambulancias/camiones/ganado".

En las edificaciones la gente dispone de salidas en condición de normalidad y una o varias salidas en caso de emergencia (en singular).

Así la acepción 25 de "de" sea "para" la frase debería ser **Salida para casos de emergencia** (otra vez en singular) y si se quiere hacer la elipsis para que el cartelito sobre la puerta no tenga que ser muy grande se puede dejar en **Salida para <strike>c̶a̶s̶o̶s̶ ̶d̶e̶</strike> emergencia**.

Es otro caso en el que el uso común nos hace parecer que es correcto